# Simplest way to delete object from list of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove an item from a list. Usually pretty obvious but the problem is that those items are objects and I want to remove them by one of their attributes.

Is there a more graceful way to do this than what I have below?

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myList = []
    myList.append(Item("item1", "green"))
    myList.append(Item("item2", "blue"))

    # Try to remove object with name "item2"
    index = None
    for i, val in enumerate(myList):
        if val.name == "item2"
            del myList[i]
```

Comment: You can always use the `repr` dunder method

Comment: You can also use something like `map(attrgetter('my_attr'), my_list)` `attrgetter` can be found in the `operator` built-in library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) method [`filter(function, iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).

`filter()` applies a *`function`* to each element of an *`iterable`* - if the function evaluates to `True`, this element is in the resulting generator. 
If the function evaluates to `False` the element is skipped.

The result of `filter(..)` is a generator, so you need to put it into a list (or use the generator result if you just need it once).

Demo:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, num):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.name} - {self.num})"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myList = []
    for n in range(0,20):
        myList.append(Item(str(n), n))

    newList1 = list( filter(lambda x: x.num % 3 == 0, myList) ) 

print(myList)

print(newList1)
```

Output:

```
# input to filter
[  (0 - 0),   (1 - 1),   (2 - 2),   (3 - 3),   (4 - 4),   (5 - 5),   (6 - 6), (7 - 7),   
   (8 - 8),   (9 - 9), (10 - 10), (11 - 11), (12 - 12), (13 - 13), (14 - 14), (15 - 15),
 (16 - 16), (17 - 17), (18 - 18), (19 - 19)] 

# result of filter
[(0 - 0), (3 - 3), (6 - 6), (9 - 9), (12 - 12), (15 - 15), (18 - 18)]
```

Comment: Nice and well explained. But maybe an example that tackles the exact case the OP described would be desirable (that is: remove object with name "item2").

Comment: @floella - `wyw = list( filter(lambda i: i.name != 'item2', [Item("item1","green"), Item("item2","blue"), ] ) )`  should do the trick. A solution using a list expression is preferable imho though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a super simple way:

```
[x for x in myList if x.name != 'item2']
```

That is, simply make a new list with the items you want.  You can assign it back to `myList` if needed.